# Excluding version from artifact name in Jenkins job repository

Tags: maven, jenkins, war

I use

```
<build>
        <finalName>myname</finalName>
```

in my `Maven` pom and my artifact in the projet's target directory does get called **myname.war**. However, when `Jenkins` does the build, it stores it under **myname-${project.version}.war** and I can't find a way to store it as myname.war in Jenkins. I would like to avoid having version because the artifact is deployed in the web container under the context **myname**, not **myname-${project.version}** and it is deployed there using Jenkins' [copy](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Copy+Artifact+Plugin) and then [deploy](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Deploy+Plugin) plugins.

I am looking either for a way to forcefully omit the version from the artifact in Jenkins OR set some instructions in **myname-${project.version}.war** to deploy it as **myname**.